Custom resource with API Platform to return generic statistics
I'm using Symfony 7.1 and API Platform 4.
I want to return some data (counting the number of companies by status). This doesn't relate directly to a Doctrine entity, but instead is a custom database query that pulls in and processes data. I have plenty of other data I wish to expose via the API that doesn't map to an entity. It's my first time using API Platform, so I could be missing something obvious.
I've created App\ApiResource\CompanyStatistics as follows:
<?php

namespace App\ApiResource;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use App\State\CompanyStatisticsStateProvider;

#[ApiResource(provider: CompanyStatisticsStateProvider::class)]
#[Get(provider: CompanyStatisticsStateProvider::class)]
class CompanyStatistics
{}

I've then created App\State\CompanyStatisticsProvider as follows:
<?php

namespace App\State;

use App\Repository\CompanyRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;

class CompanyStatisticsStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private CompanyRepository $companyRepository
    )
    {}

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        if ($operation instanceof Get) {
            $countsByStatus = [];

            foreach ($this->companyRepository->getCountsByStatus() as $row) {
                $countsByStatus[$row['status']] = [
                    'companyCount' => $row['company_count'],
                    'otherData' => $row['goes_here'],
                ];
            }
            return [
                'countByStatus' => $countsByStatus,
            ];
        }

        return null;
    }
}


The issue I'm having is that when querying this via the API, I get the following:
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/CompanyStatistics",
  "@id": "/api/company_statistics",
  "@type": "Collection",
  "totalItems": 2,
  "member": [
    {
      "active": {
        "companyCount": 1,
        "otherData": "goesHere"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I don't think it should be being returned as a collection. How can I fix this to make it appear as just flat data, not a collection? Is there a better way to create an endpoint that exposes random / non entity data?

Edit
I fixed this by setting the following at the top of the ApiResource\CompanyStatistics class:
#[ApiResource(
    provider: CompanyStatisticsStateProvider::class,
    operations: [ new Get() ],
    paginationEnabled: false
)]


Pretty sure that if you provide #[ApiResource(...)] without explicitly naming resources, you get all of them. See here for examples with just some of the operations. The Get definition should be inside the ApiResource definition.

Thanks. I've managed to fix it by making the CompanyStatistics ApiResource accept some parameters in it's constructor.
